# Extract element by ID from string?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string which contains this text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ExtractDiv test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Apples and oranges</p>
    <div id="main">
        <ul style="list-style-type: upper-roman">
            <li>&#196;pfel</li>
            <li>Birnen</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Men and women</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I need a JavaScript function which gives me back a DOM element with a specific ID **as a string** from this text, for example:

```
function ExtractElementByIdFromString(HTMLString, IdString)
{
  var ExtractedElement = ???(HTMLString, IdString);
  return ExtractedElement;
}
```

So the RESULT of this function in this case would be:

```
<div id="main">
    <ul style="list-style-type: upper-roman">
        <li>&#196;pfel</li>
        <li>Birnen</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I have no document. This is only a *STRING*.

Comment: Can you show me the working code? I will then accept your answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can parse an HTML string with the native [DOMParser](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface):

```
var str = "<!DOCTYPE……………" // your HTML string

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html")
```

Then just use regular DOM methods:

```
console.log( doc.getElementById("main") )
```

Note that using a DOMParser is more efficient and safer than inserting the string somewhere in your document's innerHTML, because only the structure will be created — `<script>` elements won't be executed, images won't be loaded, CSS will no try to apply to it, no rendering will occur, etc.

Comment: @user1580348 what do you mean, it does not work? I've tried it and it does return the element with id="main". Do you get any error? (the returned value is an Element, but you can get a string from that easily with DOMSerializer or just innerHTML)

Comment: @user1580348 Touffy's code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/w2hzrr9c/), `DOMParser` is supported in modern browsers only though.

Comment: @user1580348 In your question you said you want to return a DOM element, the imgur image shows, that you're returning a string. Which one you actually want?

Comment: @Teemu Sorry, this was a misunderstanding. Of course I want a string result. I've corrected my question.

Comment: @Touffy with innerHTML I only get the HTML *INSIDE* the tags (I suppose that's why it is called innerHTML). How can I get the HTML string *INCLUDING* the element tags?

Comment: Is `DOMParser` supported by mobile browsers?

Comment: @user1580348 it's supported by *most* browsers including mobile, but as you found out there are some laggards. You can polyfill DOMParser for them, e.g. https://gist.github.com/eligrey/1129031

Comment: @Touffy What is a polyfill? Does this mean it replaces DOMParser in browsers like Opera where DOMParser does not work? How must it be used?

Comment: @user1580348 Yes exactly. You check `if 'DOMParser' in window` to see if it's supported. If not, then you load the polyfill, which functions just like the native DOMParser (although it's usually less efficient and might lack some features) so that you don't need to write different code for old browsers.

Comment: @Touffy I am not sure what you mean with "you load the polyfill". Shouldn't the reference to the "polyfill" be included in the HTML head section like this: `<script src="html-domparser.js"></script>`?

Comment: @user1580348 well, not necessarily. If the browser doesn't need it, you don't want to load the script at all. So what you do is, only if DOMParser isn't supported, you `document.write()` a `<script>` tag to load the polyfill. You can do that anywhere in the document, as long as you don't use DOMParser before.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a temporary element, put the `HTMLString` as a content to it, then use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to get an element with passed `id`. Something like this:

```
function ExtractElementByIdFromString(HTMLString, IdString) {
    var result,
        temp = document.createElement('div'); // Create a temporary element
    temp.innerHTML = HTMLString; // Set the passed string as HTML to the temporary element
    result = temp.querySelector('#' + IdString).outerHTML; // Find an element with the passed id
    return result;
}
```

[A working demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehg1wxLe/).