# How do I find an element by the id in an html page in node.js

Tags: node.js

So, I served an `html` page with a `node.js` file, and I want to know how I can get an element in the `html` file in that `node.js` file.

I have tried youtube and google and can't find what I am looking for.

Here is my code:

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id='iwwinm'>I want to be stored in a node.js var? How?!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Node.js

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

__dirname = path.resolve();

let server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
  console.log('req made: ' + req.url)
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var mRS = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html', 'utf8');
  mRS.pipe(res)
})

function log() {
  console.log('hi')
}

server.listen(3000)
```

In the end, I simply want to get the content of that `p` element, and log it in the `node.js` console!

Comment: Aren't you going about this backwards? You're serving up your file from your node server and THEN you're trying to get a value from the page you just served? Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to parse html, then query element like jquery.

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p id='iwwinm'>I want to be stored in a node.js var? How?!</p>
  </body>
</html>
`)

console.log($('#iwwinm').text(''))
```

Comment: See also this related question on how to extract an html element from a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894426/extract-element-by-id-from-string

Comment: and this answer on how to implement it for node.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398419/trying-to-use-the-domparser-with-node-js
contains some alternatives to cheerio like jsdom: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom